# MS Access: Subform doesn't work, but the main form does

Tags: ms-access

I have a form with a button that updates data in a table, form which works perfectly. However, when I add it as a subform on a tab paged form, it no longer does. Access prompts out asking for the `[Forms]![MyForm]![textbox]` variable, although it exists and is filled out. I'm guessing there's a different way to reference a subform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to the name of the form, the name of the subform control, the form property and the name of the control (reference [MVPs](http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm), [MS](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/113352) ). You have MS Access 2010, so you can use the query design window and intellisense to build the relevant string, it will work put something like:

```
 [forms]![Gestiune]![SubformControlNameHere].Form![idInchirieri]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Not only do you always deliver the right answer, but you also explain it very well!

Answer (score 0):

The expression `[Forms]![MyForm]![textbox]` probably appears within the query used as RowSource of a ComboBox or ListBox on the subform. This subform is now no longer `Forms!MyForm` but

```
Forms!MainForm!MySubformControl.Form
```

I don't know the correct names, adapt them accordingly.

Change the expression to something like

```
Forms!MainForm!MySubformControl.Form!textbox
```

- `Forms` is the collection of the open forms. *(invariable)*
- `MainForm` is the name of the form with the tab control. *(adapt)*
- `MySubformControl` is the name of the control containing the subform. *(adapt)*
- `.Form` designates the subform itself. *(invariable)*
- Finally `textbox` is your TextBox. *(should be ok, otherwise adapt)*

Comment: I found something similar online and it doesn't work for me. My exact syntax is: `[Forms]![Gestiune]![TabCtl0]![ClientiSub].[Form]![idMod]`
Up to TabCtl0 the intellisense autocompletes it, but it doesn't afterwards. `ClientiSub` is the subform name, I also tried with `Clienti` (the tab name) and it still doesn't work.

Comment: There is never any need to refer to a tab control when referencing a control. Control names must be unique across the entire form, whether there is tab control or not. See http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm, which is pretty comprehensive.

Comment: After `TabCtl0` you must place the name of the control holding the subform. It may have another name as the form being used as subform. The subform is not placed directly on a form, instead it is embedded in a subform control.

Comment: Remou is right. I removed the tab control from the path. Also the query could be used as row source of a ComboBox, for instance. FloIancu, can you tell us more about where this expression is exactly and where the referred textbox is? It is difficult to give you a precise answer without knowing the details.